# Find duplicate rows and change a value in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm trying to realize a query that find duplicates in a table and increment by 1 their s/n value.

Example:

```
Name    S/N     id      
A       004      1
B       005      2
C       007      3
C       007      4
C       007      5
D       004      6
```

Will be:

```
Name    S/N     id      
A       004      1
B       005      2
C       007      3
C       008      4
C       009      5
D       004      6
```

I'm using ms access.

Comment: You increment the last with the same name by 1

Comment: Ok this question has a few problems:

1. Is S/N a varchar field? Cause with a leading 00 it looks like it.

2. What happens if and entry can't be increased by 1, cause the result would be a number that already exists? Is any increase ok? Does it have to be 1?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
No s/n is an int. My table is filled in a way in wich cant happens your second point. It has to be increased by 1.

Comment: Regarding the second point. May it be that your example is wrong, then? Cause I see two times "004" and if you increase the duplicate by one, you get "005", which already exists.

Comment: In that case, they have a different name, so technically they aren't duplicates. You have to change S/N only according to names

Answer (score 0):

Okay then assuming your table is called Table1, you could use the following code:

```
select
    base.[Name]
  , base.[S/N]
    + (
          select
            count(*)
          from Table1 as a
          where 1=1
            and a.[S/N] = base.[S/N]
            and a.[Name] = base.[Name]
            and base.id >= a.id
      )
    - 1 as [S/N]
  , base.id
from Table1 base
```

This solution is not performant on huge datasets, but unfortunately there is no row_number() in Access (it's a terrible tool). Basically what it does is create an artificial row number with a partition by Name,S/N and then adds the row number minus 1 to the S/N. So if there is only one entry, then 0 will be added, otherwise the first duplicate gets +1, second +2 etc.

You don't need the 1=1 of course, but it's a habit :)